# Linking Google Sheet to Hosted Feature Layer in ArcGIS Developer Online (free version)

Tags: layers, arcgis-online, operations-dashboard, google-sheets

I am trying to create a ArcGIS Online Dashboard that is linked to Google Sheets. I have done this successfully in a regular ArcGIS Online map by publishing the Google Sheet as a CSV file and uploading accordingly; however, this type of layer cannot be read by the Dashboard since it is not a "Hosted Feature Layer".

Therefore, I tried to upload the Google Sheet using the following steps:

1. Navigated to "Add Item from Cloud Drive"
2. Selected the correct Google Sheet
3. Reviewed the data (coordinates, etc.)
4. Uploaded the Google Sheet

Despite following these steps, I constantly get a "An Error Occurred" message and the new hosted feature layer is blank. I have tried changing the "Share Settings" on the Google Drive, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue.

Go through and make sure none of the cells in your Google Sheet are exceeding the 255 character limit. This was the source of my error.

If this doesn't resolve the issue, remove any additional sheets that you might be using. Make sure there are no special characters in your field names. Remove any hyperlinks. And go into your browser settings and delete any stored cookies, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing you can also use KOOPJS and it's Google Sheet Provider to serve PBF Vector tiles and ESRI FeatureServer and then give those URL's to your Portal/AGOL to create webmap,webappbuilder application, etc